# Copy specific Column from a .csv file to another .csv file and save it as a new .csv file issue

Tags: python, csv

Let's say File1 is the file where i want to copy the column from, and File 2 is the file where I want that column to be pasted at, and once pasted, save this file as a new file with extension .csv. It seem like a simple code to do, yet my first atempt of the code has giving me this error "AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writerow' 
".Clearly, I seem to have no idea what I am doing wrong here. So i was wondering if you guys could help me. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import csv

File1 = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/dyn_0.csv'
File2 = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/HiSAM1_data_160215_164858.csv'


with open(File1, "r") as r, open(File2, "a") as w: 
     reader = csv.reader(r, lineterminator = "\n")
     writer = csv.writer(w, lineterminator = "\n")

     for row in reader:
         w.writerow(row[0])
```

If the question needs formatting please let me know. Also, if you think the code will not do what I want, a hint of where I can get started will definitely help. Please keep in mind I am a slow learner so if you can show me how to make it work step by step that will be a huge help! I just need some starter so I can follow on it and write my own.  Thanks :o)

Comment: Try using `writer.writerow([row[0]])`. That should get rid of the `AttributeError` and copy (just) the first column to the other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most immediate problem is that `w` is the file object... you want `writer`. But you've got a few other issues. First, you described 3 files, not two. Next, you need to actually insert the column. Finally, you have to decide what to do if the two files have different lengths. In this example I assumed you wanted to take the first column from the first csv file and insert it as the first column in the merged result. I tweeked file names to (hopefully) make it more clear.

The following code has several techniques for merging csvs as noted in the comments. You need to change them to your circumstances.

```
import os
import csv

File1 = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/dyn_0.csv'
File2 = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/HiSAM1_data_160215_164858.csv'

root, ext = os.path.splitext(File2)
output = root + '-new.csv'

with open(File1) as r1, open(File2) as r2, open(output, 'w') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    merge_from = csv.reader(r1)
    merge_to = csv.reader(r2)
    # skip 3 lines of headers
    for _ in range(3):
        next(merge_from)
    for merge_from_row, merge_to_row in zip(merge_from, merge_to):
        # insert from col 0 as to col 0
        merge_to_row.insert(0, merge_from_row[0])
        # replace from col 1 with to col 3
        merge_to_row[1] = merge_from_row[3]
        # delete merge_to rows 5,6,7 completely
        del merge_to_row[5:8]
        writer.writerow(merge_to_row)
```

Comment: thanks for the help!!!! Yeah that is exactly what i want, yet i just tried this but it gave me this following error TypeError: _csv.writer object is not an iterator. I am going to try to figure this out since I thik this program will lead me to what i need.

Comment: Taking a second look, `zip` is a great tool for building up multiple iterators and I should have used it. So I changed the example to match. On python 2, use `izip` instead.

Comment: it worked! it worked!! but now my original file is lost and the new file only has the new column, in other words, it has copied the first column of file1 to file 2 3 times and did not save the rest of the data of the second file that it is sensitive for the analysis.... is there a way to do the same thing but without deleting everything from the original file?

Comment: I opened the output file "w" mode assuming you'd want to clear the file each time. If you want to append, use "a" instead.

Comment: yes that seemed to work awesome! i guess the only one thing I need to know is how can i get around in deleting the first column only of file2 (the file where I am pasting the first column of file1)  and only copy  the file1 column from let's say line 3  and below. That way i only copy the numerical values and not the titles of that file1 first column... Hope that made sense ahahah! ty so much man, you've been a real help!

Comment: If you wanted to, say, replace col 0 instead of inserting a new col 0, you would `merge_to_row[0] = merge_from_row[0]`. If you wanted to get rid of columns completely, lets say cols 3 4 and 5, you would `del merge_to_row[3:6]`. If you wanted to skip headers, you'd have to go back to an earlier example... in fact, I will put that in.

Comment: dude you are awesome! so i made it work, but I am still puzzled about once I get the first column replaced in the file2 the column  starts from line 0, is there a way to paste the column starting from line 3?

Comment: Dude no matter what you've been a great help! I thank god for people like you ;)